# How to show that $V= \text{Im }f \oplus \text{Ker }g$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U, V, W$ be vector spaces over a field $K$, and let $f: U \to V$ and $g: V \to W$ be linear transformations such that $g \circ f$ is an isomorphism. I have to show that  $V= \text{Im }f \oplus \text{Ker }g$.

I really don't know what to do, I've solved some similar problems but always with just one linear transfromation, not with two. I hope you can give me some hint or idea to handle this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Point one: show $\operatorname{Im} f \cap \ker g = \{0\}$. Point two: show every $v \in V$ can be written as $f(u) + k$, where $g(k) = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That sounds like an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$g\circ f\colon U\to W$; call $h\colon W\to U$ its inverse; then you have a way to go from $V$ back to $V$ with $\varphi=f\circ h\circ g$. If $v\in V$, consider $v=\varphi(v)+(v-\varphi(v))$ and go on.